# Helm chart template: How to render complex structure as is

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

**Scenario**: We have 2 settings: `commonSettings` and `appSettings`. If a key is present in both `commonSettings` and `appSettings`, then the one in `appSettings` overrides the other.

**Issue:** The complex structure value for key `Logging:` is getting rendered as `map[Name:Test]` instead of `{ "Name": "Test" }`. More details below.

Can someone help me in this regard? Thank you.

```yaml
{{- define "settings" }}
{{ range $k, $v := .Values.appSettings }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
{{ end }}
{{ range $k, $v := .Values.commonSettings }}
{{ if (not (hasKey $.Values.appSettings $k)) }}
{{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{- end }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  labels:
    app: test-app
data:
  appSettings.json: |-
  
{{- include "settings" . | fromYaml | toPrettyJson | nindent 4 }}
```

**Values.yaml**

```yaml
commonSettings:
  {
    "Color": "Green",
    "Make": "Toyota"
  }
  
appSettings:
  {
    "Color": "Red",
    "Logging": {
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    "Model": "Highlander"
  }
```

**Actual Output:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  labels:
    app: test-app
data:
  appSettings.json: |-
    {
      "Color": "Red",
      "Logging": "map[Name:Test]",
      "Make": "Toyota",
      "Model": "Highlander"
    }
```

**Expected output:**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-configmap
  labels:
    app: test-app
data:
  appSettings.json: |-
    {
      "Color": "Red",
      "Logging": {
        "Name": "Test"
      },
      "Make": "Toyota",
      "Model": "Highlander"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for my situation. I am able to use `merge`. Following is the entire example which you can paste in `https://helm-playground.com/` to try out yourself.

**configmap.yaml**

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: rpwebservice-configmap
namespace: testservice
labels:
    app: testservice
data:
  appSettings.json: |-
  {{- $dict := merge .Values.appSettings .Values.commonSettings }}
  {{- $dict | toYaml | fromYaml | toPrettyJson | nindent 4}}
```

**values.yaml**

```yaml
commonSettings:
  {
    "Color": "Green",
    "Make": "Toyota",
    "Logging": {
      "Name": "Common",
      "Foo": "Bar"
    }
  }
  
appSettings:
  {
    "Color": "Red",
    "Logging": {
      "Name": "Test"
    },
    "Model": "Highlander"
  }
```

**Output**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: testservice-configmap
namespace: testservice
labels:
    app: testservice
data:
  appSettings.json: |-
    {
      "Color": "Red",
      "Logging": {
        "Foo": "Bar",
        "Name": "Test"
      },
      "Make": "Toyota",
      "Model": "Highlander"
    }
```